# SQL Server / SSIS - Dynamic T-SQL, NVARCHAR(MAX) Difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I am writing some dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql = '...'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

If I execute this from SSMS, the query executes successfully because it is less than 8000 (7787 to be precise) characters. If I execute this from SSIS (using an ADO.NET connection) the query fails because `NVARCHAR(MAX)` is the equivalent of `NVARCHAR(4000)`.

I understand this is something to do with compatibility - the connection from SSIS needs to support more than just SQL Server.

What are my workaround options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, I'd go this way (in order of preference):

1. Find a way to do it without using dynamic SQL (such a large dynamic script must be a nightmare to debug or change)...
2. Split some of it out into stored procedures and call those from your dynamic SQL.
3. Split it into a number of smaller sub queries.

Comment: I agree with Paddy, don't use dynamic SQL if you don't absolutely need to.  And option 2 certainly makes sense too.

Comment: I completely agree. This is one of those pieces of code that has been knocking around for a few years in desperate need of a proper rejig.